# Yii custom validation rule not called on validate()

Tags: php, forms, validation, yii

When a user registers for my application the following validation rules are called before submission:

```
public function rules()
{   
    return array(
        array('email, firstName, lastName, password, passwordConfirm, telephone', 'required'),
        array('club, email, firstName, lastName, level, password, telephone', 'length', 'max'=>45),
        array('passwordConfirm', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'on'=>'register'),
        array('email', 'isUniqueEmailAddress'),
    );  
}
```

The first three validation rules complete successfully, but the fourth (a custom validation method) does not.  It should call the function 'isUniqueEmailAddress' and perform the following:

```
/*
* Returns true if there doesn't exist a user in the database with the submitted email
*/
public function isUniqueEmailAddress($attribute, $params)
{
    //if (User::model()->find('email=:email', array(':email'=>$this->email)) !== null)
    //{
        $this->addError('email', 'Email account already exists');
    //}
}
```

As you can see, I've even commented out all logic to simply ensure that a validation error is sent back to the registration form, but no errors are returned on validation().  I've read [Yii's Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/) and scoured the forums but cannot understand why my custom validation method is not being called?

Comment: What are you using to check the errors in the model? `$model->getErrors()`?
What is the scenario of the model?
Do you have a custom `beforeValidate()` method? If so, are you returning true in it?
Have you tried putting `CApplication::end();` into that validation method to see if it really is being called?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when attempting to set a flash message in a controller after calling $model->save(). It was a code formatting issue which caused a logic error.

For example, in the model I had something like this:

```
public function validateNumItems($attribute, $params) {
  $this->addError($attribute, 'Validate Items Failed');
}
```

In theory this should have caused the form submission to fail every time for debugging purposes. But it never did.

My controller's update action looked like this:

```
  public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if (isset($_POST['Collection'])) 
    {
      $model->attributes = $_POST['Collection'];
      if ($model->save())
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Data saved!");
        $this->redirect(array('index'));
    }

    $this->render('update', array('model' => $model, ));
  }
```

The missing brackets around the $model->save() test created by Gii caused a logic error when I added new lines. Putting the brackets in place fixed things.

```
  public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if (isset($_POST['Collection'])) {
      $model->attributes = $_POST['Collection'];
      if ($model->save()) {
          Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Data saved!");
          $this->redirect(array('index'));
      }
    }

    $this->render('update', array('model' => $model, ));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array('email', 'exist')
```

like this.

```
public function rules()
{   
    return array(
        array('email, firstName, lastName, password, passwordConfirm, telephone', 'required'),
        array('club, email, firstName, lastName, level, password, telephone', 'length', 'max'=>45),
        array('passwordConfirm', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'on'=>'register'),
        array('email', 'exist')
    );  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented with some possible reasons your code isn't working (it looks right), but in this case you can just use the `Unique` validator.

`array('email', 'unique')` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it's working fine -

```
public function rules()
    {   
        return array(
            array('email, firstName, lastName, password, passwordConfirm, telephone', 'required'),
        array('email', 'email','message'=>"The email isn't correct"),
            array('email', 'uniqueEmail'),
        );  
    }
```

your custom function, write into same model -

```
public function uniqueEmail($attribute, $params)
    {
        if($user = User::model()->exists('email=:email',array(':email'=>$this->email)))
          $this->addError($attribute, 'Email already exists!');
    }
```